# hiveserver2 starts and then very quickly stops

Tags: hadoop, hive

I run hive on my Mac Sierra and basically the client hive works.  However, when I start hiveserver2 it runs a little and then exits.  I start hiveserver2 by 2 methods, either

```
hive --service hiveserver2
```

Or

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin/hiveserver2
```

The result and output are the same in both cases:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/hive/2.1.0/libexec/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

Probably I need to get some logs but I cannot. I configure logging in hive-site.xml as follows:

```
<property>
<name>hive.server2.logging.operation.enabled</name>
<value>true</value>
<description>When true, HS2 will save operation logs and make them available for clients</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>hive.server2.logging.operation.log.location</name>
<value>/usr/local/Cellar/hive/2.1.0/libexec/log</value>
<description>Top level directory where operation logs are stored if logging functionality is enabled</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>hive.server2.logging.operation.level</name>
<value>VERBOSE</value>
...
```

However, I do not see anything created in the log directory

Comment: try running in a different port (default port is 10000). hive --service hiveserver2 --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10001

Comment: The same problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to check using beeline if it's on or off without a doubt. In one example  the HiveServer2 process is running on localhost at port 52000:

```
$ beeline
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:52000 username password org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:52000>
```

,

Another thing is to use start as in [documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/cdh_ig_hiveserver2_start_stop.html). To start HiveServer2:

```
$ sudo service hive-server2 start
```

To stop HiveServer2:

```
$ sudo service hive-server2 stop
```